# Prove that $w(x)$ the derived set of $O_T^+(x)$ is $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a perfect metric space $T:X \to X$ be a continuous map. 
Define $O_T^+(x)=\{T^n(x): n \in \Bbb N\}$. If $\overline{O_T^+(x)}=X$

Prove that $w(x)$ the derived set of $O_T^+(x)$ is $X$.

I have proved that $w(x)$ is closed. Now I was trying to show that for any $y \in X\setminus w(x)$ we'll get $x \in w(x)$.

Comment: You probably need some additional assumptions. Is $T$ surjective? What about constant functions?

Comment: I think now the problem has been sorted out. Anyway look for the proof with surjectivity as well. Thanks.